# I can't change the image size

Tags: html, css

```
    >my css
       
        body {
          background-color: rgb(52, 51, 51);

          text-decoration-color: aliceblue;

          font-family: Georgia, 
          "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
          text-transform: uppercase;

          font-weight: bold;
        }

        li {
          float: left;
          list-style-type: none;

          padding: 10px;
          display: block;
          width: 90%;
        }

        #images {
          border: 1px solid #ddd;
          border-radius: 4px;
          padding: 5px;
          width: 10%;
          height: auto;
          max-width: 50%;
          object-fit: contain;
        }
      >my html
   <html>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en-US">
       <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta name="description" content="candy fruit mushrooms" />
        <meta name="author" content="MelL" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="candy, fruit, mushroom" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="camera.css" />
        <title>photoshop</title>
      </head>

    <body>
      <hearder>
        <h1>CAMERA</h1>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        
           </ul>
         </nav>
         </hearder>
        <main>
        <h2>RESENT</h2>
          <p>
      slice of fat, kjfjngknklgj jvnbjhvhnn jhnhnjhnjhnjnhjhnbjbnj
      ngjnkjgntfjngjtnjknjgnjjnjkjbnjkbjnjjnbjgnjnjknjkynjnjnjnjn
      htjftgjtfnjkntjnjnjnkjgynkjnjknkjnjknjnjknjhjkjkhjkhjkgnbjn
          </p>
          <div id="images">
            <img src="./photos/cracked.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="./photos/cup.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="./photos/boss.jpg" alt />
            <img src="./photos/eagly.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="./photos/dark.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="./photos/freeway.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="./photos/hiway-1.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="./photos/hiway-2.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="./photos/hiway-3.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="./photos/jamel.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="./photos/headphone.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="./photos/momma.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="./photos/nervous.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="./photos/throwup.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="./photos/shirt.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="./photos/room.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="./photos/portrait.jpg" alt="" />
           </div>
          </main>

         <footer>
          <nav>
           <ul>
             <li>instagram</li>
             <li>facebook</li>
             <li>e-mail</li>
             <li>Contact</li>
             <li>about</li>
        
           </ul>
         </nav>
         </footer>
        </body>
        </html>
        </html>
```

> I'll show you my html, and css.

> My jpeg images are way to, big, and I tried to change the width, and height, but it didn't work I also tried object-fit element, but it didn't work either. I don't know why nothings working.
> could putting a negative symbol make the image decrease for example: width: -10px

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple, remember that the last style applied to your element will prevail, and that styles applied by hashtag symbol are implemented over id's.

You can debug your styles live in your web browser pressing F12 and using inspector tool.

```css
#images
{ 
  max-height: 10%; 
  max-width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<img id=images src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1198272365/es/foto/objeto-ondulado-colorido.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=cI1p1k0jRzDSJ2tLpWVqzy6xlSmx9pOf2YyaudwBaS4=">
</html>
```

With your example would be

```css
        li {
          float: left;
          list-style-type: none;

          padding: 10px;
          display: block;
          width: 90%;
        }

        .images {
          border: 1px solid #ddd;
          border-radius: 4px;
          padding: 5px;
          width: 10%;
          height: auto;
          max-width: 50%;
          object-fit: contain;
        }
```

```html
<html>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en-US">
       <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta name="description" content="candy fruit mushrooms" />
        <meta name="author" content="MelL" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="candy, fruit, mushroom" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="camera.css" />
        <title>photoshop</title>
      </head>

    <body>
      <hearder>
        <h1>CAMERA</h1>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        
           </ul>
         </nav>
         </hearder>
        <main>
        <h2>RESENT</h2>
          <p>
      slice of fat, kjfjngknklgj jvnbjhvhnn jhnhnjhnjhnjnhjhnbjbnj
      ngjnkjgntfjngjtnjknjgnjjnjkjbnjkbjnjjnbjgnjnjknjkynjnjnjnjn
      htjftgjtfnjkntjnjnjnkjgynkjnjknkjnjknjnjknjhjkjkhjkhjkgnbjn
          </p>
          <div id="images">
            <img class=images src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1170732816/es/foto/estructura-de-conexi%C3%B3n-digital-geom%C3%A9trica-del-ordenador-antecedentes-de-tecnolog%C3%ADa-de.jpg?s=612x612&w=is&k=20&c=oJ2FmdaXK-hF7m78QbzC_wOJARrJfrsEIgwrxpAjoG8=" alt="" />
            <img class=images src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1366645360/es/vector/imagen-abstracta-brillante-en-un-estilo-moderno.webp?s=612x612&w=is&k=20&c=tSNezIG_QdD_vsfdSU66TX6G9Rpf40-O_tYhi87O2-c=" alt="" />
            <img class=images src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1170732816/es/foto/estructura-de-conexi%C3%B3n-digital-geom%C3%A9trica-del-ordenador-antecedentes-de-tecnolog%C3%ADa-de.jpg?s=612x612&w=is&k=20&c=oJ2FmdaXK-hF7m78QbzC_wOJARrJfrsEIgwrxpAjoG8=" alt />
            <img class=images src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1366645360/es/vector/imagen-abstracta-brillante-en-un-estilo-moderno.webp?s=612x612&w=is&k=20&c=tSNezIG_QdD_vsfdSU66TX6G9Rpf40-O_tYhi87O2-c=" alt="" />       
           </div>
          </main>

         <footer>
          <nav>
           <ul>
             <li>instagram</li>
             <li>facebook</li>
             <li>e-mail</li>
             <li>Contact</li>
             <li>about</li>
        
           </ul>
         </nav>
         </footer>
        </body>
        </html>
        </html>
```

Comment: I didn't see anything in my terminal that needed to be debugged nor any problems. I put max height and width, but there were no changes to the size of the image. the images are big and it it's taking up all the space in my viewport.

Comment: Post an example of your html code also (an image tag not working), to check what's the problem. When debugging CSS there are no errors displayed, the goal is make changes on the fly to see what problem could exist, and what styles are being applied to an element.

Comment: I edit my question and put my hmtl in there. and I ask another question.

Comment: You should use a class to your images. `.images <img class=images ...>`

Comment: the class element didn't work, I also tried using style in line (<img style=" width: 30px"/>), that didn't work either. Maby, I need to use Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

```
                             > So to object-fit the images you need to make a div element with its own class, and then an img with its own class. I didn't know that at first that's why I struggled to make the object-fit work on my images.
                    >html
                            <div class="box">
                                 <img class="images" 
                                  src="./photos/cracked.jpg" alt="" />
                            </div>
                 
                      >css
                               .box{

                                    background-color: #ddd;
                                    width: 50px;
                                    padding: 3rem;


                                   }



                              .images {

                                  border: 1px solid #ddd;
                                  border-radius: 4px;
                                  object-fit: cover;
                                  width: 30px;
                                  height: auto;

                                      }
                             >Thanks me
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).